# Vim map esc key in insert mode without losing undo sequence?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I have one question about Vim. I understood map as just the equal command till now. Here's the thing. I put `imap <c-o> <esc>o` in my `.vimrc` file to start a new line. As to the reason why not just map `<CR>` is that I followed the suggestion by Drew Neil that using `esc` and `o` command to replace  so that I can use `undo` command line by line. However, when I use `<c-o>` to start a line, the `undo` command doesn't work, **which means Vim doesn't  switch the mode even I map the `<esc>`** ! I don't know whether is feature or bug of Vim? I will appreciate it if you help me in some ways.

Comment: I tried this and undo worked for me.  Do you have `o` remapped elsewhere in your vimrc?  99% of the time you should use `inoremap` instead of `imap`.  The former will use the default mapping while the latter respects custom mappings.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I followed your suggestions and failed:(.I suppose that you may not get what I mean, 'undo' actually works for me. The thing is, I write a line, and start a new line, finished, start a new line again. And switch to normal mode press 'undo' command, Vim just deletes all my lines that I type in insert mode instead of one line.(I thought mode switch should happen when I press  '<c-o>'.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I get it now, I hope :).  I've given you a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inoremap <c-o> <c-g>u<esc>o` to get the desired behaviour you want.  `<c-g>u` breaks the current undo sequence (see `:h i_CTRL-G_u`).

I actually never thought about why having `<esc>` in insert mappings doesn't count as breaking the undo sequence.  I could certainly theorize why but doing so is dangerous in an SO answer, so I won't :)

Edited to add: Simpler would be: `inoremap <c-o> <c-g>u<cr>`